# I deleted my Google security question by mistake and there is now no way to get another one

Tags: google-account, security, user-accounts

I agree that a two-step sign in procedure is better than the old security question method.  However, we live off-grid where there is no cellular phone signal.  So the two-step logon process will not work for me.  I would rather have a security question than having nothing at all.  Google should consider folks like us in very rural America where mobile phones simply do not work.

So, is there any other way that I can have a two-step sign in procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Google's two-factor authentication can deliver the authentication code via a voice call as well as a text message, so you can set it up using your landline phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Google offer several alternatives for using the two-factor authentication

- Use a security key
- Use the Authenticator app
- Print a backup set of security codes